# Salesforce Remote Access Authorization Error

Tags: oauth, salesforce

I am new to developing a Salesforce app and I am using OAuth 1 for authentication.
I am able to generate the Request Token, and I re-direct the user to the salesforce site.
Once I enter my credentials, I get a

> Remote Access Authorization Error
>   There was a problem in setting up your remote access

with

> oauth_error_code=1800

In my Login History page, it shows `Status` as `Success` for `Application` type `OAuth`.
I don't get any entry in my `Debug Logs` page.
I have enabled `Development Mode`.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using oauth2 instead, its much easier to use.

Comment: I am using oauth in a program for connecting to other services as well, and Twitter does not support oauth2 yet :(

Comment: I found the error: I hadn't put oauth_consumer_key in the redirect url.

Comment: @superfell Can you help me out in this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191311/remote-access-application-authorization-issue-in-salesforce-iphone-phonegap-ap

Answer (score -2):

So https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success is a stub URL for callbacks - and that is the screen you are seeing there, and the access_token variable is your session ID for the user. So the OAuth flow is working correctly.

In the code, you might check to see if `oauthResponse.access_token` is getting set correctly. If so, it looks like:

```
sfw.login( setupHomeView );
```

That is what should tell it to move from that page to the next UI page.

You might also check out the Force.com Mobile SDK ([link](http://developer.force.com/MobileSDK)). It also includes PhoneGap and has a great OAuth wrapper built in.