# oAuth2 Issue in Salesforce PhoneGap iPhone Application (Remote Access Application Authorization Issue)

Tags: iphone, cordova, salesforce, oauth-2.0, phonegap-plugins

I have created an iPhone application using PhoneGap. I have followed code from this tutorial:

[Building PhoneGap Mobile Applications Powered by Database.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Building_PhoneGap_Mobile_Applications_Powered_by_Database.com)

I have logged in successfully and got struck in this screen:
[image]

I am unable to move to other screens to access data. Here is the url that got generated after successful login:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success#access_token=0000&refresh_token=0000&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fna12.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%000C&issued_at=0000&signature=qqqq&scope=id+api+refresh_token
```

Do I need to add cosumer key to this url? Here is my callbackurl:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success
```

What would be the problem? Did I miss anything?

Comment: I got this error when I hadn't been requesting the correct scopes.

Answer (score 0):

So https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success is a stub URL for callbacks - and that is the screen you are seeing there, and the access_token variable is your session ID for the user.  So the OAuth flow is working correctly.

In the code, you might check to see if:

```
oauthResponse.access_token
```

Is getting set correctly.  If so it looks like:

```
sfw.login( setupHomeView );
```

Is what should tell it to move from that page to the next UI page.

You might also check out the Force.com Mobile SDK:
http://developer.force.com/MobileSDK

It also includes PhoneGap and has a great OAuth wrapper built in.